# What join to get all instances of a key shared by both tables?

Tags: sql

What is the most efficient way to get the result with these two starting tables using T-SQL?

Table1

| id | value1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |

Table2

| id | value2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | E |
| 3 | F |

Desired result:

| id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | E |
| 2 | B | null |
| 3 | null | F |

```
drop table if exists dbo.test1;

create table dbo.test1
(id int,
value1 varchar(50)
);

drop table if exists dbo.test2;

create table dbo.test2
(id int,
value2 varchar(50)
);

insert into dbo.test1
values
(1,'A'),
(2,'B');

insert into dbo.test2
values
(1,'E'),
(3,'F');
```

this works but seems very inefficient
Union all keys first, then join in the values from the other 2 tables

```
select p.id, a.value1, b.value2
from
(select id from test1
union
select id from test2) p

left join dbo.test1 a
on p.id = a.id

left join dbo.test2 b
on p.id = b.id
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? This feels like a good usecase for a `FULL OUTER JOIN` but those aren't supported on every platform.

Comment: @JNevill using T-SQL on MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FULL JOIN` and `COALESCE()`, for SQL Server.

Example:

```
 SELECT
  COALESCE(a.id,b.id) AS id
  ,a.value1
  ,b.value2
FROM test1 AS a
FULL JOIN test2 AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

Fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d1f62122bff5ca91fa31c25818cc58f7

Comment: In this example text you're saying FULL JOIN, but in the example query it says FULL OUTER JOIN. Since the word OUTER is optional in MSSQL, they both work. But it might be an idea to atleast use the same wording in the same answer.